# Responsive Email with Internal CSS

Tags: css, email, responsive-design

I currently send out multiple desktop version newsletters that have a "View as Mobile" link with a hosted mobile version, but I am trying to explore options for displaying a mobile version right when the user opens the email.

I've read about responsive designs with variations of the following code using internal stylesheets

```
    @media screen and (max-width : 320px), screen and (max-device-width: 320px)
```

But according to http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ not all ESPs allow or read internal style sheets. In short, is there a good way to have responsive emails using the above code or is it not viable due to lack of support?

Answer (score 0):

In general, email clients are bad at supporting css (for a few reasons) so you may want to stay away from doing too much with CSS. That being said you can find support table here http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C6/media_queries_in_html_emails and just make sure you use CSS to progressively enhance for supporting clients instead of punishing those that dont.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andy in 'email clients are bad at supporting css'.  This is a general rule and has been for ages.

That said - when we talk about Mobile Email clients, there aren't any phones out there running MS Outlook '95, if you know what I mean!

Look at the market breakdown of email capable smartphone devices out there, and you'll see that support is present in a higher percentage than the desktop world.

At our company, more than 50% of the readership of our weekly emails is on **iPhones alone**. that includes desktop Gmail, Hotmail, Outlook etc.  We're seeing a continuing trend toward mobile usage being our focus, with desktop playing second fiddle.

We're not running out and building mobile websites, but we're tailoring our emails to be mobile friendly.  For example: [Everguide Weekly Guide Email](https://everguide.createsend.com/reports/viewCampaign.aspx?ID=2F8ECF7CF6D8DE4C)

**So regarding your CSS** - it is in fact very difficult at this time to ensure media queries are being read and interpreted correctly.

We have found that Android does not like to play ball as iOS does, but with some good tweaks and code hacks, we're getting there.

Here's an example of one of our transactional email templates - that is capped at 520px wide, but scales to device widths etc when on different devices.

It takes testing and patience to get this right. For our next project, I will be starting from scratch using this new guide from Campaign Monitor: [Campaign Monitor's guide to Responsive Email Design](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/)

I will be building it up bit by bit, Using adobe shadow (this has been renamed recently I think) and various on-screen emulators to make sure the code is truly responsive every step of the way.

If I were you, id nail down your own 'boilerplate' first, save this off, then make all future email designs off this template.

I specialise in this - and there is no tried and true method as yet.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with creating responsive e-mails is that lot of clients just ignores the style tag, so there is no way to build real responsive e-mails...

But there is a trick... ;)

You can build the e-mail in a mobile-first way, so the basic html is the mobile version.
If you create the media queries in a way, that they "recreate" the original desktop version, then you have a kinda good solution...
So if a client ignores media queries, then it will show the mobile version.

I found a great template what works in a way that I mentioned, you can find it here:
http://internations.github.io/antwort/